# creating a css triangle in percentage

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a div that is square on the top site and flows into a triangle,

the square part is not so hard, and works fine, but the triangle part is a bit harder.
The box needs to change from size with the screen size, in the square i did this by using % in the width and height, but i cannot use the % sign in the border property

The code i have on this moment

HTML

```
 <div id="overV12" class="menuItem" onclick="scrollToT('#overons')" onmouseover="setHover('overV12')" onmouseout="setOldClass('overV12')"><div class="menuInner">Over V12</div></div>
```

CSS

```
div.menuItem 
{
height: 5.38%;
width: 7.44%;
position: fixed;
background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 12;
text-align: center;
top: 4.3%;
}

div.menuItemHover
{
height: 5.38%;
width: 7.44%;
position: fixed;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 12;
text-align: center;
top: 4.3%;
background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
}

div.menuItemActive
{
height: 7.8%;
width: 7.44%;
position: fixed;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 12;
text-align: center;
top: 4.3%;
background-color: Black;
color: White;    
}
```

The JavaScript is used for setting the class: i did this because i use a parralax library and wanted to set the button on "active" on a certain height

i hope someone can help me (and perhaps others) with this problem

jsfiddle
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/t9cEy/)
My idea is that when the div is set on class menuItemActive, it will have the arrow, else not
This is only when it is set on active

Comment: Can you provide code sample via jsFiddle?

Comment: Done, i edited in the question body

Comment: you may also check this answer for a responsive triangle : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24808936/1811992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by using javascript instead of percentage,
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLW5Z/1/)
I hope this can help some other people as well

The java script i used is this:

```
$(document).ready(setSize());

function setSize() {
   var halfWidth = ($('.div1').width()) / 2;   
   $('.div2').css('border-width', ('50px ' + halfWidth + 'px 0 ' + halfWidth + 'px'));
   $('.div2').css('top', ($('.div1').height()));
}
```

Comment: For future reference I made a version that resizes as the window changes + some css stuff.  http://codepen.io/clouddueling/pen/zlsaJ?editors=110

Answer (score 7):

This uses two overlapping divs to create the triangle and [this method](http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio) to make things fluid while maintaining the aspect ratio.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/SpSdR/22/)**

```
.div1 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
.div2 {
    width:70%;
    min-height:70%;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    border:1px solid blue;
    position:absolute;
    left:15%;
    top:65%;
    z-index:1;
}
#container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
}
#dummy {
    padding-top: 100%;
}
#element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I left it without a background so you could see how it works.

Comment: I was trying to make the arrow fluid as well, 
but since a border with cant be set with precentage, i had to solve this problem with javascript, i used your fiddle as a base and created this, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLW5Z/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but i your fiddle is not the result i am looking for.
I already got it and pasted it in the first command.
@apaul34208 i would like you for your effort thoug

Comment: I like this solution. seems to me a good solution to make the triangle fluid

Answer (score 1):

You can do triangles in CSS.

Here's a link to an article, outlining the general technique: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/. There's also a variety of similar/other approaches for slightly different situations I've found and used, just search "css triangles".

To briefly describe the technique: it uses four borders on an element (if you wanted a down arrow, you'd put this element inside your `<div id="overV12">`, or depending on the effect, apply it to your inner `<div>`). Some are transparent, some aren't. By changing the border widths and colors, you can generate CSS triangles, which can be fully customized to form different angle degrees, lengths, etc. I've also seen this concept used to create CSS-only speech bubbles as well as tooltip handles.

I've used this technique extensively, and in my use cases, it worked in every browser (although I do remember having a problem with IE6 on one project).

Answer (score 0):

its better to use a background image for custom shaped like this
it'll make it easier to manager and you can make it adjust itself for different resolutions easily

Comment: if i use a image (witch i did in the beginning) then it stretches out and gets quit ugly on bigger screens.

Comment: for what exact purpose is this used? a button?
you problem with pixxelting is that using a small original image
use a PNG of about 256*256 and then use the code to make is smaller
so assuming that is is a button, even at highest resolutions it would be in good shape

Comment: it is beeing used for a menu button, and i am not sure if the size of the button image bigger is then the requestd size on the screen, i will look into this tommorow. (when i am in the presence of my pc again)